# How to render turntable of .obj file

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine, transforms, camera

I am new to blender. I have a .obj file that I need a rendered turntable of (meaning I need to spin the obj and render a frame every 10 degrees or so). Importing the .obj file works fine. However, I cannot even add a camera to the scene. I am trying this:

```
cam = bpy.data.cameras.new("Camera")
cam_ob = bpy.data.objects.new("Camera", cam)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(cam_ob)
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.context.scene.objects["Camera"]
```

I also tried this:

```
bpy.ops.object.camera_add(view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0.0, 0.0, -4.0), rotation=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
```

but when I run

```
bpy.ops.render.render()
```

It says

```
ERROR: Cannot render, no camera
```

What's the correct way of doing this, and what's the best way of repeatedly rendering the .obj while spinning it?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you really need to automate the process with python? How will you make sure the camera is the right distance from the camera so it's framed well without checking it manually?

Comment: Another script earlier in the pipeline calculates the bounding box and orients the obj file so that the sizes and shapes are pretty consistent. I'm pretty sure that after trying out a few camera positions, I'll find one that works well with everything. Yes, this needs to be automated because it's running on a headless server.

Comment: Upvoted for you :) But please accept the answer, if mont29 has solved your issue.

Comment: Oh ok didn't know I was supposed to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the new camera as the active one for the scene, before rendering, like this:

```
bpy.context.scene.camera = cam_ob
```

To rotate an object around its **Z** axis, just do:

```
from mathutils import radians
my_obj.rotation_euler.rotate_axis('Z', radians(10))
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't have enough rep to upvote but it works now.